# can an aircraft land on an aircraft

Tags: aerodynamics, wing

Assuming the larger (receiving) AC has holding mounts and the smaller AC can slowly approach without contacting the tail. Possible example, land a cesna on the back of a C130
Would the weight of the smaller aircraft be compensated by the lift generated from it's wings?

Comment: Used to happen all the time with blimps.

Comment: The other question doesn't cover additional weight / additional lift.